# Jackson - annotate the class to be excluded from serialization when some property meets specific criteria

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following use case, lets say I have an object CAR with a list of WHEEL objects

```
class Car{
   List<Wheel> wheels;
   //getters and setters..
}
```

Now lets say that the Wheel class have a property `boolean isWinterTyre;`

I would like to know if there is any annotation, custom serialization stuff maybe or something else, to annotate somehow a `Car` class or the `Wheel` class itself to exclude all wheel objects having property `isWinterTyre = true` contained in '`wheels`' list while serializing my Java '`Car`' instance to JSON representation.

Comment: What output in json are you looking for?

Comment: The json structure will be the same, I just want to skip some wheels depending on their properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible using custom serializes. See tutorial [here](http://www.techtraits.com/Programming/2011/11/20/using-custom-serializers-with-jackson/).

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
class Wheel {
   //getters and setters..
}


public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Wheel> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Wheel value, JsonGenerator generator, 
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
                 if(value.getSomething() == something) {
                     //Output Wheel using the generator
                 } else {
                     //skip it
                 }
            }
}
```